# Javascript, innerHTML and getElementById

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I'm completely new to javascript and a friend helped me with a problem, I know what it does but I can't really understand some parts, I've made some comments in the code with some questions I hope you can answer them.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Uppgift 15</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script>
            var  resultat = 0;

            function addera(){

                var t1 = Math.round(object("t1").value);

                if (t1 != 0){
                    resultat += t1;
                    object("t1").value = ""; 
                }
                else{
                    object("resultat").innerHTML = resultat; // where does "object" come from, what does innerHTML do?
                }
            }

            function object(id){ // i dont get this at all what does this do is there any other way to return?
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="t1">
        <input type="button" onClick=addera() value="resultat">
        <p id="resultat"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: object is just a function that returns an element.

Comment: it look'y like your new to programming not only javascript ;)

Answer (score 0):

The object function returns the html element with the specified ID, while innerHtml lets you edit the HTML associated to that element

Answer (score 0):

the object is returned from your object function your function simply gets element by id from dom and returns it

```
var  resultat = 0;

                function addera(){

                    var t1 = Math.round(object("t1").value);

                    if (t1 != 0){
                        resultat += t1;
                        object("t1").value = ""; 
                    }
                    else{
                        object("resultat").innerHTML = resultat; // object is returned from     object function according to parameter of function the function takes this parameter as id
    and selects the element from dom 

                    }
                }

                function object(id){  
                    return document.getElementById(id);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `object()` is already defined in your code, in which `document.getElementById(id);` will return the element with the specified ID.

The `innerHTML` property sets or returns the inner HTML of an element.

Here `object("resultat").innerHTML = resultat;`

Is same as
  `document.getElementById("resultat").innerHTML = resultat;`